# Let $R=k[[ X_1,X_2,X_3]]$ and $S=R/(X_1X_3,X_2X_3)$. Can one compute $\ell_S(S/(a_1^i,a_2^j))$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[[ X_1,X_2,X_3]]$ and $S=R/(X_1X_3,X_2X_3)$. Let $x_i$ be the natural image of $X_i$ in $S$. Set $a_1=x_1+x_3$ and $a_2=x_2+x_3$.
$a_1,a_2$ is a system of parameters of $S$. So $\ell_S(S/(a_1^i,a_2^j))$ is finite ($i$ and $j$ are natural numbers). I can see that $\ell_S(S/(a_1,a_2))=2$

Can one compute $\ell_S(S/(a_1^i,a_2^j))$?